# Can I prevent a C++ dll from loading in Python Ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, c, dll, ctypes

I'd like to know if it's possible prevent or allow a dll to be loaded by python ctypes, based on whether a condition is true **from within the dll.**

*Some background:*

My application uses various calculation algorithms, which I prototyped in Python, and then reimplemented in C++ for a speed boost. I still use Python for the application "glue" and GUI. I'm accessing the functions in the dll using a ctypes wrapper.

I now need to secure the software, so that it will only run if a security dongle is present. The open nature of Python makes this difficult, so I'd like to be able to stop a python script loading the dll unless a function which checks the dongle is present returns True.

Example Python wrapper:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_int , c_float, c_bool

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('my.dll')

cpp_sum = lib.sum
cpp_sum.argtypes = [c_int,c_int]
cpp_sum.restype = c_int

def wrapped_sum(value_1,value_2):
    return cpp_sum(value_1,value_2)
```

And the code for the my.dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>

#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLEXPORT int sum(int a, int b) 
    {return a + b;}

//pseudo dongle code:
bool is_dongle_present(){
    if dongle present return true
    else return false
```

Ideally the dll would fail to load if dongle_is_present returned false. Can anyone help?
Please tell me if this question is unclear!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DllMain` function to your library.

> An optional entry point into a dynamic-link library (DLL). When the
>   system starts or terminates a process or thread, it calls the
>   entry-point function for each loaded DLL using the first thread of the
>   process. The system also calls the entry-point function for a DLL when
>   it is loaded or unloaded using the LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary
>   functions.

You could prevent dll load by returning `FALSE` on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`:

> When the system calls the DllMain function with
>   the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value, the function returns TRUE if it succeeds
>   or FALSE if initialization fails. If the return value is FALSE when
>   DllMain is called because the process uses the LoadLibrary function,
>   LoadLibrary returns NULL. (The system immediately calls your
>   entry-point function with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH and unloads the DLL.) If
>   the return value is FALSE when DllMain is called during process
>   initialization, the process terminates with an error

See [DllMain MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) for the additional information.

Comment: Note that doing almost anything (including OS calls) from DllMain is unsafe as it is called during a kernel loader lock.

Comment: Thanks Ari0nhh . I've given this a go, and have run into linker errors which I'm struggling to get round (DllMain is already defined). 
Based on your warnings Richard, I'm leaning towards defining a global "ENABLED" variable which I can set from my application (assuming the dongle presence allows that) and is checked by each function before it allows the return of a value. It sounds safer!